# ImportRow() not copying DataRows to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two tables that I want to "join" together. The first one has all columns that the second one has but the data is incomplete. Both tables have an ID which I will use to stitch them together. A merge doesn't work since the second table has more rows and it contains identical ID's various times.
This example will explain it better:

```
OldTable1:
+----+-------+---------+--------+
| ID | Name  | PhoneNr | Address|  
+----+-------+---------+--------+
| 1  | Tim   | 0       |        |  
+----+-------+---------+--------+
| 2  | Frank | 0       |        | 
+----+-------+---------+--------+

OldTable2
+----+---------+--------+
| ID | PhoneNr | Address|  
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 12345   | Avenue |  
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 67890   | Street | 
+----+---------+--------+
| 2  | 55555   | Alley  | 
+----+---------+--------+

NewTable:
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| ID | Name  | PhoneNr | Address |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| 1  | Tim   | 12345   | Avenue  |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| 1  | Tim   | 67890   | Street  |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| 2  | Frank | 55555   | Alley   |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
```

Here is my code:

```
DataTable newTable = oldTable1.Clone();

    foreach (DataRow drOld1 in oldTable1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow drOld2 in oldTable2.Rows)
        {
            if (drOld1["ID"].Equals(drOld2["ID"]))
            {
                DataRow newRow = oldTable1.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = drOld1.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];

                newRow["PhoneNr"] = drOld2["PhoneNr"];
                newRow["Address"] = drOld2["Address"];
                newTable.ImportRow(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't tell what is wrong. Everything seems to work until I get to the line with the ImportRow. The newRow includes all the correct information, it just doesn't add the row to newTable. I looked through several related questions and none of the answers solve my problem. I can't replace ImportRow() with Add() since it is another DataTable. OldTable1 and newTable have the exact same columns because I created newTable cloning the scheme from OldTable1. What am I missing here?

**SOLUTION:**
As pointed out correctly by aguertin the reason it wasn't working was the following:

> The method NewRow() detaches the row which will cause the ImportRow()
>   method to be ignored and no exception will be thrown either.

My personal solution was using the old rows of the first table instead of creating a new one. Everything works now as intended.

```
DataTable newTable = oldTable1.Clone();

        foreach (DataRow drOld1 in oldTable1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow drOld2 in oldTable2.Rows)
            {
                if (drOld1["ID"].Equals(drOld2["ID"]))
                {
                    drOld1["PhoneNr"] = drOld2["PhoneNr"];
                    drOld1["Address"] = drOld2["Address"];
                    newTable.ImportRow(drOld1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"Everything seems to work until I get to the line with the ImportRow."* and then what happens?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because the cloned row is detached and detached rows can't be imported.  It does not throw an exception either,  it will just ignore it.

Comment: Exactly, nothing happens. Detached because I created it using NewRow() from another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method NewRow()  detaches the row which will cause the ImportRow() method to be ignored and no exception will be thrown either.

Use Add().... even though you say can't just create a temporary dictionary/table and store the values in there.

Comment: This is in fact the correct answer. Thank you! Unfortunately I could not make it work using the Add() function. I replaced `newTable.ImportRow(newRow);` with `newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);` and it gives me the following Error: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: This row already belongs to another table._
I could solve it another way as you can see in my edit though